# Simple GNU make backslash and variable assignment

Tags: variables, makefile, backslash

In many Makefiles I have seen the following variable assignment structure:

```
TARGETDIR=somedirectory

OBJS = \
"tab" $(TARGETDIR)/main.o
```

I believe this means to put the object file in "somedirectory" and call it main.o.

My understanding of the backslash used above is that it extends a long line to the line below. The above is not a long line, so why is the backslash used to make this a multiline statement? Would the above have the same results as:

```
OBJS = $(TARGETDIR)/main.o
```

Thank You
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result is the same. `make` uses space(s) as delimiter between items in list variables, and a \newline counts as zero characters, so it doesn't interfere with anything. Having said that, tabs do have reserved meaning elsewhere in makefiles, so I would have avoided putting a tab there.

After this, your question boils down to 'The programmer didn't *have* to do this, so why *did* they?' The answer, of course, is 'because they could'.

If you want a possible reason, imagine that the programmer might add extra lines (targets) later, and stylistically prefers that the first line doesn't have a different indentation from the others. So, they put it on its own line from the outset. Thus saving a few seconds of reorganisation later on!

And, in fact, I've been known to use \newline-and-space delimited lists of source files. Again, it's just a stylistic choice. Use whichever way you like!